# Issues driving a simple motor driver

Tags: transistors, mosfet, motor, dc-motor, mosfet-driver

I am using the following motor driver to drive a motor via a pwm.
[image]

I can successfully drive the motor, but I get small 'jumps' with current spikes when I change the duty cycle of the pwm.
I am using a 20khz and 3.3V pwm.

What can you recommend to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you describe these "'jumps' with current spikes"?

Comment: When I change the pwm duty I see the power supply go up to 0.40A and then back down to about 0.20A, and in the process I hear like little knocks coming from the motor.

Comment: how quickly is the duty changing? Higher current is expected if the motor is accelerating, but little knocks aren't.

Comment: Can you show us the Oscilloscope waveform of the 'jumps' pictures?

Comment: Christianidis Vasileios The jumps are more physical and auditory, the waveform on the oscilloscope is a simple square, completely normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mechanical torque is a product of mass of inertia and angular acceleration \$T=J\alpha\$, meanwhile the electrical torque is proportional to the current \$T\propto I\$. When you increase the voltage the higer current accelerates the motor until the back EMF generated voltage from motor rises to approx. the applied voltage. So nothing unusual there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. is it feasible in your opinion to add a capacitor to alleviate these spikes?

Comment: No, rather a ramp to increase/decrease PWM duty ratio. But you should do also a scope trace, there might be something else, for example a transition from discontinuous conduction mode to continuous.